# Print a Custom doc property

Tags: vba, word-2010, custom-properties

Here is my  current code.

```
Sub PrintMasterTime()

Dim PropVal As Integer
    PropVal = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(MasterTime).Value
    Print PropVal

End Sub
```

Compile Error: `Method not valid without suitable object`

Not sure why it's not printing. `"MasterTime"` is the name of my custom document property.

Comment: [`CustomDocumentProperties()` MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212718%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [Returning an object from a collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211950%28v=office.11%29.aspx).  I don't think you can call a `.Value` from a collection property.

Comment: Can you call a .value from a Regular Document Property and store it as a variable? That would be enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `CustomDocumentProperties` with a string. You forgot the quotes.

```
PropVal = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("MasterTime").Value
```